# Accessing Current Context in a PersistentConnection

Tags: signalr

From how I've understood it HTTPContext.Current is not always available for a SignalR Hub to access, so we should look to use Context.* or Context.Request.GetHttpContext().

However when I use a PersistentConnection, I don't believe I can use a HubCallerContext and HTTPContext.Current is still not something that is reliable; so what should I be using?

[Unified static class between HttpContext and SignalR HubCallerContext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21659789/unified-static-class-between-httpcontext-and-signalr-hubcallercontext)

Comment: It should be possible to call `GetHttpContext` directly on `request` parameter of PersistentConnection methods. Have you tried this?

Answer (score 0):

Dax is correct, it is possible to call GetHttpContext directly from the request parameter of the PersistentConnection.