# How can I access the user's Claims in Identity 2 when using SignalR Hub with an ASP.NET MVC 5 project?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, signalr

I have an application that is written using c# on the top of Asp.Net MVC 5 Framework.

I am using [SignalR 2.2.2](https://www.asp.net/signalr) to create WebSocket communication between the browser and the server to push messages from the server to the browser.

However, I need to be able to access my `ClaimsIdentity` object for the logged in user so I can determine what messages to podcast.

Typically, I would access the identity claims like so

```
IPrincipal user = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User
IIdentity identity = user.Identity;
var claims = (IEnumerable<Claim>)identity.Claims;
```

However, this line `System.Web.HttpContext.Current` returns null; preventing me from obtaining the currently logged in user.

I am guessing that SignalR create a synchronous connection which is why `System.Web.HttpContext.Current` is null.

I also try to use the `HubCallerContex` as suggested by this [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21659789/unified-static-class-between-httpcontext-and-signalr-hubcallercontext) but the `Context` object is also null.

```
System.Web.HttpContextBase httpContext = Context.Request.GetHttpContext();
```

How can I correctly access the user claims with in my Hub?

I added the following key to my `appSettings` in my Web.config as I am using Framework 4.5.1

```
<add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true"/>
```

Comment: Are you using SignalR hubs? There is [Context.User](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.aspnet.signalr.hubs.hubcallercontext.user(v=vs.118).aspx) property, have you checked it?

Comment: @Zabavsky the `Context` object itself id null.

Comment: Where are you trying to access the context from?

Comment: From the Constructor. My constructor called the base() class

Comment: The constructor of what? The hub?

Comment: I am asking because SignalR [first creates the hub and then populates the context](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/blob/7dc8921376743b73856cb1f7bb9ca1db8de1abe2/src/Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Core/Hubs/HubDispatcher.cs#L455-L464) so the context is initialized when the instance is created and therefore you cannot access it when in the ctor.

Comment: Yes the constructor of the Hub class

Comment: There is documentation for this, here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/security/hub-authorization.  Have you correctly annotated your hub methods?

Comment: @BrendanGreen yes I added it but still same issue

Comment: Show more of your code.  Your hub definition, and the code that is making the calls.

Answer (score 3):

If using SignalR hubs and want to authorize the methods under the same Hub one would have to use the **Authorize** attribute on the Hub. i.e.

```
[Authorize]
public class MessagingHub: Hub
{
    public Task Send(string data)
    {
        return Clients.Caller.SendAsync("Send", "Data To Send");
    }
}
```

In order to access Claims or User Identity in the Hub method e.g **Send** above, then one would have the following:

```
[Authorize]
public class MessagingHub: Hub
{
   public Task Send(string data)
  {
     var identity = (ClaimsIdentity)Context.User.Identity;
     //one can access all member functions or properties of identity e.g, Claims, Name, IsAuthenticated... 
      return Clients.Caller.SendAsync("Send", "Data To Send");
  }
}
```

If using Json Web Tokens (JWT) or just token authentication as was the case for me then, from the client side this is what could be used to invoke the Hub's Send method.

**NB: For my case the client is an Angular 6 app.**

```
import { HubConnection } from "@aspnet/signalr";
import * as signalR from '@aspnet/signalr';
...
private _messagingHubConnection: HubConnection | undefined;
public async: any;
...
constructor(){}
...
 SendMessg(): void {
    if (this._messagingHubConnection) {
      this._messagingHubConnection.invoke('Send');
    }
  }
...

ngOnInit(){
    this._messagingHubConnection= new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
      .withUrl("messaging", { accessTokenFactory: () => "jwt_token" }) //have a logic that gets the current user's authentication token from the browser 
      .build();

    this._messagingHubConnection.start().then(() => {
        this.SendMessg();
      }).catch(err => console.error(err.toString()));

    if (this._messagingHubConnection) {
      this._messagingHubConnection.on('Send', (data: any) => {
        //data represents response/message received from Hub method'd return value.
      });

    }
}
```

**NB: I am using .Net Core 2.1 so be sure to register the Hub.
also this is with the assumption that signalR is already setup**

For .Net Core, ensure that in your StartUp.cs you have;

```
services.AddSignalR(); // under ConfigureServices
```

and

```
app.UseWebSockets();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseSignalR(routes => {
    routes.MapHub<LoopyHub>("/messaging");
});
```

**NB: From the [issues on GitHub for SignalR](https://github.com/aspnet/SignalR/issues/2316) I realized the order of the above is important just in case anyone is developing any issues. i.e. From my understanding the above order is correct.**

Technically I have answered the question above but from a .NET Core & Angular context; I guess most if not all implementations follow the same approach.

Comment: Does not answer question.  Question is about Asp.Net MVC 5 not ASPNET Core.

Answer (score 0):

All of you'll missing out one important thing.

Unlike controllers you wont be able to access the claims within constructor within Hub. Access the claims once its connected. like below.

```
 [Authorize]
    public class YourHub: Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Hub
    {

          public override async Task OnConnectedAsync()
          {
             ...
             var identity = (ClaimsIdentity)Context.User.Identity;
          }
  }
```